# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord

У меня появилась проблема с кодом.

В данном коде:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.run = async  (bot, message, args, owners) => {

async function writeJsonOw() {
    let stringData = JSON.stringify(owners)
    await fs.promises.writeFile("./owners.json", stringData);
}

async function setOw(id) {
    if (!owners.owner.includes(id)) {
        owners.owner.push(id);
        await writeJsonOw();
    }

}



if(message.author.id === '690984466335662111'){
    console.log( owners )
    console.log( owners.owner )
    console.log( typeof owners )
    let id111 = args.splice(0).join(" ")
    if(id111 === "" || id111 === " "){
        let emb1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("RED")
            .setTitle(`Добавление доступа к боту`)
            .addField('Ошибка:','Укажите ID пользователя')
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send( emb1 )
        return
    }
    if(owners.owner.includes(id111)){
        let emb2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("RED")
            .setTitle(`Добавление доступа к боту`)
            .addField('Ошибка: ', 'У данного человека уже есть VIP')
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send( emb2 )
    }else{
        setVip(id111);
        let emb3 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('GREEN')
            .setTitle(`Добавление доступа к боту`)
            .addField(`Доступ выдан.`, `Юзер: <@${id111}>`)
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send( emb3 )
    }

}

}

module.exports.help = {

name: 'addowner'

}
```

Выводит ошибку: `(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

Содержимое JSON файла: `{
  "owner":[]
}`

Помогите, пожалуйста! Я не понимаю в чём проблема.

Comment: очевидно, что в момент вызова `includes` значение `owners.owner` - undefined.

Comment: А как это исправить?, @Grundy

Comment: Либо не вызывать эту функцию, если `undefined`, либо передавать не `undefined`

Comment: Как Вы вызываете данный модуль? Передаете ли Вы значение переменной `owners`?